# calculate the total time grouping by date and id using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

My data looks like this

```
ID  |   START_DATE          |   END_DATE                |   Chapter
1       01/03/2013 05:15:14     01/03/2013 06:20:14         1
1       01/03/2013 06:25:33     01/03/2013 06:40:11         2
2       01/03/2013 05:01:34     01/03/2013 05:30:13         1
2       01/03/2013 05:31:20     01/03/2013 06:30:13         2
2       01/03/2013 06:32:20     01/03/2013 07:20:01         3
1       02/03/2013 05:15:14     01/03/2013 06:20:14         1
1       02/03/2013 06:25:33     01/03/2013 06:40:11         2
```

I want a result like this

```
ID  | Date          |       Total Duration
1       01/03/2013          Time in Minutes
1       02/03/2013          Time in Minutes
2       02/03/2013          Time in Minutes
```

There is a way to do this with linq using C#?

Comment: You marked question with `linq-to-objects` tag. What objects do you operating on?

Comment: My object is a List<T> and the "T" objec has exactly the fields of the table. this help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group items by date and id, and calculate sum of durations for each group:

```
var query = from r in records
            group r by new { r.Id, r.StartDate.Date } into g
            select new {
               g.Key.Id,
               g.Key.Date,
               TotalDuration = g.Sum(x => (x.EndDate - x.StartDate).TotalMinutes)
            };
```

Here is [working program](http://ideone.com/SwjYeZ).

Comment: I did like the way you said and i received the message "Cant cast timespan to decimal.", i guess because the Sum method receive Func<T, decimal?> Update: Sorry, i made a mistake.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento I added link to program which demonstrates this query